# Attendance time in and out calculation for all shifts without using flag

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a face reader machine. I am getting data only employeecode and  punchdate from that machine. Here we don't have a separate machine for IN or OUT. So I cannot predict which one is IN or OUT. I used Row number concept that's also I am getting lots of duplication.

1. Multiple punches per day
2. Night shift calculation
3. miss punch

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeTimeSequence (employeecode nvarchar(500),
                                    punchdate datetime,
                                    Punchsequence nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO #EmployeeTimeSequence
SELECT employeecode,
       punchdate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeecode ORDER BY punchdate) AS PunchSequence
FROM attendance_trial; --Replace this with your dbo.AttLog table if this solution works for you
/*WHERE clause could be added here to filter for specific dates or EnrollNumbers */

--select * from #EmployeeTimeSequence
--drop table #EmployeeTimeSequence 
/* If time between punches is greater than this threashold, then it will be treated as a missed punch
      in logic below. Remove this or modify as needed. */
DECLARE @MissedPunchThreshold int;
SET @MissedPunchThreshold = 20;

CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (employeecode nvarchar(500),
                     CheckDate datetime,
                     Time_In datetime,
                     Time_Out datetime,
                     HoursBetweenPunch nvarchar(50),
                     PunchOutSequence nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO #Temp1
/* Anchor member */
SELECT ETS_In.employeecode,
       CAST(ETS_In.punchdate AS datetime) AS CheckDate,
       ETS_In.punchdate AS Time_In,
       ETS_Out.punchdate AS Time_Out,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, ETS_In.punchdate, ETS_Out.punchdate) AS HoursBetweenPunch,
       ETS_Out.Punchsequence AS PunchOutSequence
FROM #EmployeeTimeSequence ETS_In
     LEFT OUTER JOIN #EmployeeTimeSequence ETS_Out ON ETS_In.employeecode = ETS_Out.employeecode
                                                  AND ETS_Out.Punchsequence = ETS_In.Punchsequence + 1
WHERE ETS_In.Punchsequence = 1
UNION ALL
/* Recursive memebr - build on top of anchor */
SELECT ETS_In.employeecode,
       CAST(ETS_In.punchdate AS datetime) AS CheckDate,
       ETS_In.punchdate AS Time_In,
       ETS_Out.punchdate AS Time_Out,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, ETS_In.punchdate, ETS_Out.punchdate) AS HoursBetweenPunch,
       ETS_Out.Punchsequence AS PunchOutSequence
FROM #EmployeeTimeSequence ETS_In --get the time for the in punch
     INNER JOIN #Temp1 ET ON ET.employeecode = ETS_In.employeecode
                         AND ETS_In.Punchsequence = CASE
                                                         WHEN ET.HoursBetweenPunch > @MissedPunchThreshold -- if more than threshold, then treat as missed punch
                          THEN                                ET.PunchOutSequence     -- then treat the previous out punch as the next in punch instead
                                                         ELSE ET.PunchOutSequence + 1 -- else join as usual to get the next punch in sequence
                                                    END
     INNER JOIN #EmployeeTimeSequence ETS_Out -- get the time for the out punch
    ON ETS_In.employeecode = ETS_Out.employeecode
   AND ETS_Out.Punchsequence = ETS_In.Punchsequence + 1;




CREATE TABLE #att_final (employeecode nvarchar(500),
                         attendance_dt datetime,
                         Time_In datetime,
                         Time_out datetime,
                         HoursBetweenPunch nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO #att_final
SELECT employeecode,
       CONVERT(varchar, CheckDate, 23) AS dt,
       Time_In,
       CASE WHEN HoursBetweenPunch > @MissedPunchThreshold THEN NULL ELSE Time_Out END AS Time_Out,
       CASE WHEN HoursBetweenPunch > @MissedPunchThreshold THEN NULL ELSE HoursBetweenPunch END AS HoursBetweenPunch
FROM #Temp1
ORDER BY employeecode,
         CheckDate;
SELECT #att_final.employeecode,
       MIN((CONVERT(varchar(10), Time_In, 111))) AS attendance_dt,
       MIN(Time_In) AS LOGIN,
       MAX(Time_out) AS logout
FROM #att_final
GROUP BY #att_final.employeecode;

DROP TABLE #EmployeeTimeSequence;
DROP TABLE #Temp1;
DROP TABLE #att_final;
```

Comment: For the sample data you've supplied, what is the end result you're after?

Comment: Yes, but what is the result you're after here?

Comment: My sample data is   80687 2019-08-10 16:28:00.000  ,80687  2019-08-09 16:30:00.000    My Output  is   80687 2019/08/09 2019-08-09 16:30:00.000 NULL

Comment: 80687 2019/08/09 2019-08-09 16:30:00.000 NULL       80687-employyecode  2019/08/09-attendancedate  2019-08-09 16:30:00.000-login  null-logout  i am getting error like this . i cannot predict user multiple entries or miss punch . row number function failed in multiple entries and misspunch.  so please help  me

Comment: How do you differntiate between In and out times?

Comment: that is very tough task now.  before i used flag statement .I/O FLAG now its very difficult so i tried with rownumber() concept . it is also i am getting wrong values.so give some ideas for me

Comment: Please post sample data in your question in the form of insert statements to your tables. And start thinking about your schema and your code. PunchSequence is defined as varchar(10) - why? It is populated by row_number(). EmployeeCode is nvarchar(500) - same issue.  And stop the laziness - always specify the column list for insert statements.

Comment: And must you also consider the possibility that a person enters on one day and leaves on another? Or perhaps a person tags along with another when entering or leaving?

Comment: @GaneshaMoorthyArunachalam please post your tables `attendance_trial` actual structure and some sample data. Using RowNumber to differentiate between In and Out times won't work.

Comment: employeecode punchdate
20923  2019-08-13 15:30:02
20923 2019-08-13 15:30:05
20923 2019-08-13 15:33:00
20923 2019-08-13 15:33:18
20923 2019-08-14 02:30:02
20923 2019-08-18 15:30:02
20924 2019-08-13 15:30:02
20924 2019-08-14 04:30:02
20191 2019-08-11 16:28:00
20191 2019-08-09 16:26:00
20191 2019-08-12 16:28:00
20191 2019-08-11 18:26:00
20337 2019-07-01 09:07:25
20337 2019-07-01 17:46:38
20337 2019-07-02 09:01:54
20337 2019-07-02 18:11:42
20337 2019-07-03 08:54:06
20337 2019-07-03 18:22:21
attendance_trial table